# How to run a python script with its environment from another script with another environment?

Tags: python

I have two scripts: `script1.py` and `script2.py`

script1 has its environment (say, python 2), and script2 has its own environment (say, python 3).

How can I make script 1 invoke script 2, with its corresponding environment?

Thanks

Comment: so, did you solve?

Comment: @LeonardoMiquelutti no. Had to resort to creating a new process and communicating through a message bus. not a good solution, but a working solution is better the a beautiful nothing

Comment: I had to split my script into 3 parts (python 3, 2, and 3 again) but managed to run them all through a single command line. Totally agree with the beautiful nothing part @Gulzar :)

Answer (score 6):

A workaround I can think of right now is `os.system` used to execute other files.

example:

#### script1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

os.system("script2.py")
```

and

#### script2.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

print "script 2 running..."
```

`print "script 2 running..."` is great example since `python2.X` uses `print` without parentheses and `python3.X` uses `print()` with parentheses

It's important to take note of the shebangs (`#!/usr/bin/env python3` and `#!/usr/bin/env python2`) on both scripts which point to the correct entepreters/env for both scripts

`os.system` can also be used with arguments, like `os.system("script2.py data.txt")`, which is great if you want to run another script with arguments.

Comment: Will this also work in windows the same way? just specify the relevant path in the start of each script?

Comment: @Gulzar Possible with [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows).

Comment: @Gulzar it should be